# Sorting array by count of subarray

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array looking like this:

```
Array(
   ['some_first_category'] => Array(
            ['some_first_name'] => Array(
                           [0]=>'first@email.com',
                           [1]=>'second@email.com',
                           [2]=>'third@email.com',
                           [3]=>'fourth@email.com' )
             ['some_second_name'] => Array (
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com')
             ['some_third_name'] => Array(
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com',
                           [3]=>'third@email.com',
                           [4]=>'fourth@email.com' )
   ['some_second_category'] => Array(
            ['some_first_name'] => Array(
                           [0]=>'first@email.com' )
             ['some_second_name'] => Array(
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com',
                           [3]=>'third@email.com',
                           [4]=>'fourth@email.com')
             ['some_third_name'] => Array(
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com'))
```

And I want to sort the array by the number of values of that has the names, In my case I want to become this array:

```
Array(
   ['some_first_category'] => Array(
             ['some_third_name'] => Array(
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com',
                           [3]=>'third@email.com',
                           [4]=>'fourth@email.com' )
            ['some_first_name'] => Array(
                           [0]=>'first@email.com',
                           [1]=>'second@email.com',
                           [2]=>'third@email.com',
                           [3]=>'fourth@email.com' )
             ['some_second_name'] => Array (
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com')

   ['some_second_category'] => Array(
             ['some_second_name'] => Array(
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com',
                           [3]=>'third@email.com',
                           [4]=>'fourth@email.com')
             ['some_third_name'] => Array(
                           [1]=>'first@email.com',
                           [2]=>'second@email.com')
            ['some_first_name'] => Array(
                           [0]=>'first@email.com' ))
```

This means sorting categories by name by the number(count) of values of the names. Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance,

Aäron

Comment: I see that you want to sort the second level ("name") by number of child elements descending, but do you also want to sort the first level ("category") by some logic?

Comment: It isn't sorted. It's just a display specific to your needs.

Comment: I want also some one to wash my car! but if I washed and I failed, its ok to ask a friend to help me!

Comment: ppl should learn that this side is supposed to give support, not full solutions to questions. You and only you have to do the work, if you need help that's ok, but asking for the solution w/o trying anything it's just cheap.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**All you need is  [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)**

```
uasort($list, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = count($a);
    $b = count($b);
    return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? -1 : 1);
});
```

**Full Example**

```
$list = Array(
   'some_first_category' => Array(
            'some_first_name' => Array(
                           0=>'first@email.com',
                           1=>'second@email.com',
                           2=>'third@email.com',
                           3=>'fourth@email.com' ),
             'some_second_name' => Array (
                           1=>'first@email.com',
                           2=>'second@email.com'),
             'some_third_name' => Array(
                           1=>'first@email.com',
                           2=>'second@email.com',
                           3=>'third@email.com',
                           4=>'fourth@email.com' )
        ),
   'some_second_category' => Array(
            'some_first_name' => Array(
                           0=>'first@email.com' ),
             'some_second_name' => Array(
                           1=>'first@email.com',
                           2=>'second@email.com',
                           3=>'third@email.com',
                           4=>'fourth@email.com'),
             'some_third_name' => Array(
                           1=>'first@email.com',
                           2=>'second@email.com'))

    );

$list = array_map(function ($v) {
    uasort($v, function ($a, $b) {
        $a = count($a);
        $b = count($b);
        return ($a == $b) ? 0 : (($a < $b) ? 1 : - 1);
    });
    return $v;
}, $list);


print_r($list);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [some_first_category] => Array
        (
            [some_first_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => first@email.com
                    [1] => second@email.com
                    [2] => third@email.com
                    [3] => fourth@email.com
                )

            [some_third_name] => Array
                (
                    [1] => first@email.com
                    [2] => second@email.com
                    [3] => third@email.com
                    [4] => fourth@email.com
                )

            [some_second_name] => Array
                (
                    [1] => first@email.com
                    [2] => second@email.com
                )

        )

    [some_second_category] => Array
        (
            [some_second_name] => Array
                (
                    [1] => first@email.com
                    [2] => second@email.com
                    [3] => third@email.com
                    [4] => fourth@email.com
                )

            [some_third_name] => Array
                (
                    [1] => first@email.com
                    [2] => second@email.com
                )

            [some_first_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => first@email.com
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: dont put functions in parameters of functions. this is not jQuery :P

Comment: @dognose So you'd rather pointlessly assign the closure to a variable or clutter the global namespace with a function identifier then? The only reason to avoid inline closures is if you need to support <=5.2, if you need to do that you need a better job and/or host.

Comment: Thanks a lot Baba !! The usort function I already tried it myself but it doesn't maintain the key of the array's. Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: @DaveRandom A Sort function is not related to the context imho. So I might reuse it, so yes, I would put it somewhere global because then I don't need to rewrite or copy/paste it.

Answer (score 5):

Using [uksort](http://php.net/uksort):

```
uksort($yourArray, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });
```

Using **array_multisort:**

```
array_multisort(array_map('count', $yourArray), SORT_DESC, $yourArray);
```

and you can see [uasort](http://php.net/en/uasort) as well

best of luck :)

Comment: Perfect thanks...
array_multisort(array_map('count', $yourArray), SORT_DESC, $yourArray); this worked for me

Comment: `uasort($yourArray, function($a, $b) { return count($b) - count($a); });` worked great for me. if you want to reverse the sort order you can swap $a and $b in the count functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use usort function. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455537/sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-the-size-of-its-sub-arrays).

```
function sort_sub($a,$b)
{
$res= count($b)-count($a);
return $res;
}

usort($array_name,'sort_sub')
```